# Windows 10 and Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: windows-10, cloud-storage, microsoft-office-2016

I just purchased a new laptop with Windows 10, and I want to purchase Office 2016 Professional to go along with Windows 10.  However, I do not want to be forced to upload all of my files to the cloud, either through Skydrive or the Office Upload Center.  Is there any way that I can tightly control which files are uploaded to the cloud and which files stay only on my laptop?

Comment: Yes; just save your files to your local drive.  You have never been forced to save anything in the cloud unless your using a cloud version of office even then you can choose to download a local file and delete the unsaved cloud document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office Upload Center only comes into play when uploading something to "the cloud", as I only see it in action when I upload/edit a file from our Sharepoint 2013 sites.  For OneDrive, you can select what you want to upload by moving those into your OneDrive folder, as that'll sync them up to OneDrive AND will live in that location on your local machine.

It'll appear in Windows Explorer - left hand pane, typically where Favorites and This PC live.

Comment: So in other words, I can pick and choose all of the files that I upload off of my laptop, correct?

Comment: Yes you can, you can pick as many as you'd like or none at all.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  I've been looking around for an answer to this question forever, so it is great to finally get one.